# JSDOC: Tutorial config conf.json having parsing error

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I followed all the steps mentioned and still I get **"Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0"** error when I have a conf.json file in my tutorials folder. If I remove the conf.json, it works perfect. But I need the conf.json.

I have a tutorials folder with .md files and a conf.json file which looks like this

```
{
    "name_of_tutorial": {
        "title": "Test Title" 
    } 
}
```

and in my jsdoc.json file looks like this

```
{
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags": true,
        "dictionaries": ["jsdoc", "closure"]
    },
    "opts": {
        "recurse": true,
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "destination": "./docs",
        "readme": "./Content/tutorials/project_README.md",
        "tutorials": "./Content/tutorials"
    },
    "source": {
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "plugins/markdown"
    ],
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "default": { }
    }
}
```

Looks like there is a problem when reading the file and parsing it as json.
Can you help me fix it?

Comment: Your `jsdoc.json` passes json lint so looks like syntax is fine

Comment: Did you configure your editor to save as UTF-8 with BOM?